# How can I disable a certain CSS property across a web page?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome, tailwind-css

I'm trying to performance test an application, and would like to turn on/off a few expensive CSS features (blur, border rounding, opacity) to see their effect. Is there any convenient way I can do this through DevTools?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score -1):

If you grab the css classes in dev tools inspector, you could just write a reset snippet and drop it in your stylesheet.

Like so

```
.some-classname {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    filter: blur(0px) !important
}
```

This way you can go through the site and see how it looks. However if you just want to look at one page at a time, you just uncheck the css declarations in dev tools inspector.